# How do I estimate when an upstream bugfix will reach my current install?

Tags: package-management, kernel, updates

Let's take this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894378) for example, of which the following [fix](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git/commit/?h=master-next&id=5ba7812ddae2589c0a4c1ded468ce49de35774d4) exists upstream on the focal branch.

My current system is running bionic (`Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`) with kernel `5.4.0-47-generic` (as installed by `linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04`)and I would like to get a rough idea of when this fix will be backported to my current system.

I'm going to wildly make the following uninformed guess...  I figured there are 2 ways a kernel bug fix reaches my system.

If the fix is included in <s>an ABI bump</s> a patch, which means it will be available once kernel `5.4.0-x-generic`(where x > 47) becomes available in my package manager via an update to `linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04`.  Looking at the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-signed-hwe-5.4/linux-signed-hwe-5.4_5.4.0-47.51%7E18.04.1/changelog) for said package, it seems this happens roughly 2 weeks - 1 month (is this even correct??).

If the fix is not included in <s>an ABI bump</s> a patch, that means it will only be available on the next kernel release, i.e. `5.y.0-generic` (where y > 4).  This means that it will only be available when `Ubuntu 18.04.6` comes out (tentatively February 2021).

So how do I know which pathway a bug fix will follow?  Do my estimates make sense?  What is the correct way of estimating how long I'll have to live with a bug provided a fix is available upstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short version**

I think this particular fix should be arriving tomorrow or the day after.

**Long Version**

So I can help answer the general case for Ubuntu packages but it gets a little more murky for the kernel and doubly so for backported HWE kernels.  I've just gone through this process for two bugs I submitted, one for Open vSwitch and the other for GRUB.

If you find/fix a bug in an Ubuntu package, the default is to only fix it in the next major Ubuntu version (e.g. I found a bug in Focal's GRUB, it was only fixed in Groovy).  If the problem truly is a bug vs asking for additional functionality, you can submit it for a [Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) (SRU) which then will applied to currently supported Ubuntu versions.  If the SRU is accepted, it goes into the "proposed" repository for 7 days during which time at least 1 person has to mark it as a successful fix and it has to pass automated testing.  After 7 days, it then goes into the live "updates" repository.

Looking at your referenced fix, it references bug #[1892417](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1892417) which was successfully submitted for a SRU.  If we look at the [Focal proposed version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/5.4.0-48.52) we see that the code related to bug #1892417 is included.  It also appears looking at the [package's metadata](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux) that this build took place on 10 September so I believe that it should be hitting the updates repository in the next day (assuming no problems).

What I cannot tell you is, in general, the frequency of kernel releases as there is a lot of churn there. They may do releases every 14 days, once a month, or as needed.  I also do not know when the updated Focal kernel gets backported to Bionic's HWE kernel.  Comparing the release dates for 5.4.0-47.51, this last step looks instantaneous.

Comment: In the page for [Focal proposed version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/5.4.0-48.52), the first item of on the changelog links to [tracker-proposed for focal](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1894654) which further links to the [tracker-proposed for bionic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1894653).  This gives further information on the status.  As of now, it seems the update is stuck on proposed for both bionic and focal.